# Apache 2.4 mod_rewrite returns 404 for every RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I am setting up Apache 2.4.35 on a FreebBSD 11.2-RELEASE-p5 server, I enabled mod_rewrite module on it but none of the rewrite rules work, and I have spent a couple of days looking for answers but cannot make it work.

This is what I get from running httpd -M on the server:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
```

This is the Apache configuration for my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin mail@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/htdocs/myweb
        ServerName myweb.mywebsite.com

        <Location />
                SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI  \
                        \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
                SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI  \
                        \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|gz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>

###################################################################################

<Directory "/usr/local/www/htdocs/myweb">
        Options All MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        LogLevel debug rewrite:trace8
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
```

And this are the first lines of the .htaccess file located at /usr/local/www/htdocs/myweb folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Login
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^users/login(/?)$ /users/login.php [L]
```

I restarted Apache a gazillion times, nothing gets logged in the error log and every rule I try always returns a 404 error and I do not know what else to do, I am not sure if there's another module I need to enable or what else I need to do.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**UPDATE**

As requested by @KasperAgg, here is the additional info

Request:

```
POST http://myweb.mywebsite.com/users/login
```

Error Log:

```
[Sun Dec 16 14:29:40.349713 2018] [core:info] [pid 12094] [client 10.0.0.71:20255] AH00128: File does not exist: /usr/local/www/htdocs/myweb/users/login
```

Access Log:

```
[16/Dec/2018:14:29:40 -0800] "POST /users/login HTTP/1.1" 404 209
```

/usr/local/www/htdocs/myweb/users/ folder:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www  wheel   909 Dec 12 21:59 delete.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www  wheel   928 Dec 12 21:59 get.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www  wheel   892 Dec 12 21:59 getById.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www  wheel  1111 Dec 12 21:59 login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www  wheel   742 Dec 12 21:59 logout.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www  wheel  2262 Dec 12 21:59 save.php
```

What seems odd to me is that the server behaves like mod_rewrite wasn't on, and is looking for **users/login** folder instead of rewriting the url to **users/login.php** script

Comment: What is the content of (...)/myweb?

Comment: Along the .htaccess files there are folders containing PHP scripts, this is a RESTful API and mod_rewrite is needed to rewrite friendly url's to the PHP script needed to process the request

Comment: What url for example fails and does it work without the rewrite? Afaik the Directory detective should be part of the virtualhost...

Comment: All of the rewrites fail, none of them work, the one I listed fails, it's that what you are asking or am I misundertanding your question?

Comment: I see one rewrite (with condition), but if the actual 'destination' does not exist (index.php), you'll likely get a 404. Could you show an example of an URL you're trying, the 404 log (apache error/access log) and the actual content of the directory?

Comment: Just updated my question to add the requested info @KasperAgg

Comment: Did you try placing the Directory directive inside the VirtualHost? I have the feeling the AllowOverride is not applied indeed...

Comment: Just did and no change at all, same behavior

Comment: /usr/local/www/htdocs/csiapi does not equal /usr/local/www/htdocs/myweb, could that be it?

Comment: I didn't want to expose my original folder names and forgot to change it there, my bad, so sorry about that

Comment: No worries, just a red herring. One more thing though: could you try a rule with a slash? Like `^/users/...`

Comment: Just changed rule to *RewriteRule ^/users/login(/?)$ /users/login.php [L]* and it behave the same again

Comment: Darn, I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: One last thing: could you try to disable `mod_dir` and see what happens?

Comment: Just did and I get an error due to the DirectoryIndex statement in the Directory directive

Comment: Try to comment out that line.

Comment: Same thing, still got a 404

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem, it turns that having the directive

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

At the end of my .htaccess file was breaking the rewrite functionality, what's odd is that this configuration was copied from another server that was basically a clone of this one and I never experienced any errors due to that, but well, now it's working and this may help another person